# Output the filename of an inserted image inside Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I received from a client a large .xlsx file with hundreds of images directly inserted into the file.

I'm trying to output the name (or even better the filename) of the image in a new column programmatically or with a macro.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: A quick google search pulled this [forum post](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/513885-how-to-select-one-by-one-picture-on-my-sheet-with-vba.html) up. Then you'll just need to grab the `.Name` property to get the name. I didn't see anything about the file path in the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193908.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
Sub takePictureNames()
    Dim i As Integer 'use as index
    Dim Pic 'to store pictures in worhsheet

    i = 0 'init the index

    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        i = i + 1 'add 1 every time
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Pic.Name
        'Cells({a}, {b}).value = {c}
        'a = the row. Using the index to take a row at the time
        'b = define the columns you want, with a variable or hardcoded as I did
        'c = inside the Pic variable, you store a picture, one at the time, and then take the name of the pic
        'Remember: The name of the picture is the name that excel gives to the picture once is inserted, not an
        'actual file name. But if you want to use it to run a macro, will be usefull to that that name (the excel name)
    Next Pic
End Sub
```

Explanations in the comments.

Comment: Hi ElbertV, thank you for your answer and sorry for the time I took to answered you. The function works great however, it outputs the name of the image but not the correct one. For example in the E column, I have an image in each cell. Then I want to output the name in the F column. Does it make sense?